# Creating a Parallax Landscape (Scene), Different to other Parallaxes

Tags: javascript, css, html, parallax

First of all, I know there are ALOT of parallax questions out there, but they all use a different effect to what I am aiming for.

I want to create a parallax ***scene*** like used here:
http://www.firewatchgame.com/
I thought it would be easy to make different images scroll at different rates, apparently I was wrong.
I would like to recreate something like that scene using images of my own with transparent backgrounds. It's hard to explain the difference, but I am aiming for the example above, not something like this: http://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/2138_SimpleParallax/Demo/index.html (Don't get me wrong, it's a nice effect, but not what I want)

Any ideas or variations of other codes to give the desired effect?
Thanks

PS. If there are any pages that do give the same effect as desired, could a link be provided?

Comment: http://codepen.io/samdbeckham/pen/OPXPNp There is a codepen about this. It's litterly just layers of pictures. What happens is that there is a tat of transformation going on when scrollling. Also, check this https://medium.com/@hamstu/recreating-the-firewatch-parallax-effect-213694d42f4e#.6nlqzd5cl for tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dorvalla found what I was looking for:

> codepen.io/samdbeckham/pen/OPXPNp There is a codepen about this. It's litterly just layers of pictures. What happens is that there is a tat of transformation going on when scrollling. Also, check this medium.com/@hamstu/… for tutorial – Dorvalla

The medium.com website creates the exact effect I am looking for. Even relates to the Firewatch example as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for a Parallax library like this one (needs jQuery)
http://mmkjony.github.io/enllax.js/

There you can define either foreground or background images and in case you want to create a scene like in your example you have to add "data-enllax-ratio" parameters with different values. See the documentation on GitHub https://github.com/mmkjony/enllax.js